# Connected groupoids and action groupoids

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

It is written in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid,
that any *connected* groupoid $A\rightrightarrows X$ is isomorphic to the action groupoid
coming from a transitive action of some group $G$ on $X$.
I do not understand how to construct the corresponding group $G$.

Let $A\rightrightarrows X$ be a connected groupoid, where $X$ is the set of objects and $A$ is the set of arrows.
Choose an object $x_0\in X$, and consider the set $G=A(x_0,-)$, the set of all arrows starting from $x_0$.
I think that $G$ is the corresponding group. How can  I  define a composition law on $G$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take the group of automorphisms of an object.

Comment: @Martin: I want to construct a group $G$ acting _transitively_ on $X$. The group $A(x_0,x_0)$ of automorphisms of an object $x_0$ is not a desired group $G$. Rather it is the stabilizer $G_{x_0}$ of $x_0$ in $G$.

Comment: How about the group of automorphisms of the action groupoid itself?

Comment: @ZhenLin: This looks good. If  $g'\in G$, then it defines an automorphism of $(G,X)$ by $g\mapsto g' g (g')^{-1}$, $x\mapsto g'x$. If $G$ acts on $X$ effectively (with trivial kernel), we obtain an embedding $G\hookrightarrow {\rm Aut}(G,X)$, hence an embedding  $G\hookrightarrow {\rm Aut}(A\rightrightarrows X)$. We see that if $G$ acts on $X$ transitively, then ${\rm Aut} (A\rightrightarrows X)$ acts on $X$ transitively.

Comment: @ZhenLin: that's not right, think for example of an indiscrete groupoid: it has a set _X_ of objects and a unique morphism between any pair of objects. The group of automorphisms of this groupoid is the group of permutations of _X_, which is way too big: to write the groupoid as an action groupoid just take any group of the same cardinality as the set _X_ and a free and transitive action of _G_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A connected groupoid *A* can be written as an action groupoid for many different groups *G*. All the groupoid determines is *H*, the group of automorphisms of any object in the groupoid, and the index of *H* in *G*, which is the cardinality of the set of objects of the groupoid. And any group *G* with subgroup *H* of the correct index, the action of *G* on the set of cosets of *H* has action groupoid isomorphic to *A*.

This is to be expected, because if we think of *H* as a one object groupoid and of *X* as an indiscrete groupoid (the set of objects is *X*, and there is a unique morphism between any pair of objects) then the original groupoid *A* is isomorphic to the product *H* × *X*,  so the isomorphism class of *A* depends only on the group *H* and the cardinality of *X*.

UPDATE 2: Here is a sloganized answer to the question: the **equivalence** class of a connected groupoid *A* is determined by the isomorphism class of the group *H* = Aut(*x*<sub>0</sub>); the **isomorphism** class of a category is given by the data of its equivalence class plus the number of isomorphic copies of each object in a skeleton.

UPDATE: Here is a proof of the claims above "UPDATE 2".

**Claim 1**: *A* is isomorphic to *H* × *X*.

*Proof.* Choose an object *x*<sub>0</sub> of *A*, identify *H* with Aut(*x*<sub>*0*</sub>) and choose arbitrary morphisms *a*<sub>*x*</sub> : *x*<sub>*0*</sub> → *x*. The isomorphism *H* × *X* → *A* is the identity on objects and sends a morphism (*h*, *u*) : *x* → *y* to the morphism *a*<sub>*y*</sub> *h a*<sub>*x*</sub><sup>-1</sup>. (Here *u* is the unique morphism in *X* from *x* to *y*.) The inverse *A* → *H* × *X* sends a morphism *a* : *x* → *y* to (*a*<sub>*y*</sub><sup>-1</sup> *a a*<sub>*x*</sub>, *u*) --same *u* as above.

**Claim 2**: For any group *G* with a subgroup *H* of index |*X*|, the action groupoid of *G* acting on the set *G/H* of cosets is isomorphic to *A*.

*Proof.* Both groupoids are isomorphic to *H* × *X*.

As an extreme example of this, let *G* act on itself by translation and take the action groupoid. This has set of objects *G* and a unique morphism between every pair of elements. Notice all traces of the group structure of *G* are gone: the isomorphism class of this indiscrete groupoid only depends on the cardinality of *G*.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of looking at this is to use the equivalence of categories between covering morphisms of a groupoid $P$ and actions of $P$ on sets. (Recall that a covering morphism $p:G \to P$ is a groupoid morphism having unique path lifting. Not necessarily uniqe path lifting gives a *fibration of groupoids*.) Given an operation of $P$ on a set $X$ then the corresponding covering morphism may be written $P \ltimes X$, an action groupoid, and thought of as a semidirect product because it is a special case of the semidirect product for an action of a groupoid $P$ on a groupoid $H$. For this one needs a morphism of groupoids $\omega: H \to Ob(P)$, where the latter is thought of as a discrete groupoid, and an element $w: x \to y$ in $P$ gives a morphism of groupoids $w_*: \omega^{-1}(x) \to \omega^{-1}(y)$. One has to be precise on conventions to get all this right, which I won't do here.

So a groupoid $G$ has a representation as an action groupoid whenever you  are given a covering morphism $ G \to P$. This is closely related to Omar's answer, of course.